# INSERT INTO FROM: Concatenating Forename and Surname when Forename can be blank,

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a staging (RAW) table that contains one field for to hold a person's first name, and another for a person's last name. I want to insert those value on a production (DBO) table, where the person's forename and surname will be concatenated:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].Test
SELECT firstname + ' ' + lastname
      ,field1
      ,field2
      ,fieldn
FROM RAW.Test
```

Problem however is that I just found out that the firstname field can be NULL (no blanks, but NULL) in the RAW table. Considering the code I have above, this would mean that the person's name would be " Smith" (note the trailing space) instead of "Smith".

What would be the best way to check for such issue and only add the trailing space between firstname and lastname if firstname contains a value?

Note that firstname would never be blank, since the RAW table has a NULLIF conditional that replaces all blanks with NULL.

Thanks for your help and support!

P.

EDIT: Sorry for the lame edit but I made a mistake, the firsname field is the one that can be blank (which makes sense if you see the example I gave about " Smith").

Comment: `COALESCE(lastname,'')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].Test
select firstname +  ISNULL(' ' + lastname,'')
    ,field1
    ,field2
    ,fieldn
FROM RAW.Test
```

Try this. It will concatenate empty string to firstname in case of NULL in lastname

In case we are talking about Firstname that can be null your query should be:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].Test
select ISNULL(firstname + ' ','') + lastname
    ,field1
    ,field2
    ,fieldn
FROM RAW.Test
```

Comment: And the shortcut is `COALESCE(' ' + lastname,'')`

Comment: I made a serious mistake in my text. The field that can be NULL is the firstname field, not the lastname field :( As a result none of those codes seem to work since the first part of the string being null seems to be an issue.

Comment: easier:
    INSERT INTO [dbo].Test
    select ISNULL(firstname + ' ','')+ lastname 
    ,field1
    ,field2
    ,fieldn
    FROM RAW.Test

Comment: Thanks Liya! Your code is actually quite elegant and makes total sense. I was going through hoops and never thought that "hey, I can pass "firstname + <space>" to ISNULL! :) -- Thanks again. You should edit the response in case someone looks for the same question as me, though.

Answer (score 3):

Liya has a nice solution. This is another that handles both the null case and the empty string last name case as well.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].Test
select LTRIM(RTRIM (COALESCE(firstname,'') + ' ' + COALESCE(lastname,'')))
    ,field1
    ,field2
    ,fieldn
FROM RAW.Test ;
```

EDIT: Modified to allow either field to be nullable or an empty string with trimming in full effect in response to the modified requirements of the OP.

Comment: ISNULL(LastName,'') is a good alternative as well, as COALESCE is more for multiple columns/values where ISNULL assesses one column/value.

Comment: Sorry I had a semicolon where a comma should have been. Please try again.

Comment: Actually it was my fault. I said that lastname can be null, which was incorrect (see the example if " Smith"). The firstname is the field that can be null. sorry for the lame-*ss mistake.

Comment: That too. I'm a mess today. Thanks for the edit love @ypercube

Comment: Thanks a lot for your version of the code as well BZN_DBer. In fact your seems to handle both blank and nulls as you said. Even though blanks don't apply in my case, your code seems to be more complete -- although I do not understand coalesce well enough yet.

Comment: The Coalesce function takes a series of inputs. The first non-null input is the output. COALESCE(NULL,NULL,1,NULL,2) would yield 1. COALESCE (2, NULL) would yield 2. COALESCE(NULL,NULL) would yield null since no non-null values were provided.